# Obtaining Postcode Boundaries for India?

Tags: data, india, postal-code

I was wondering if there are shapefiles for postcode regions in India.

I did find some shapefiles that give the outline of the administrative units in the country but not with postcodes. Right now I am using Google Map API that highlights the region under pin-code.

---

It looks like the information is not present in public domain. It looks like either you can crowdsource the information or buy it from a thirdparty called MapMyIndia.

I found a blog by Anand.S where he wrote about his crowdsourcing idea. Other than this I couldn't really find anything interesting: [mapping-pin-codes](http://www.s-anand.net/blog/mapping-pin-codes/)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE.  It looks like you have two questions here.  One indicates you're looking for a shapefile for postcodes of India.  The other asks whether you can extract the information under the pin-code.  Please edit your question to reflect what you are actually looking for.  Possibly split them up into two separate questions.

Comment: If you are looking for a shapefile of the postcode regions, let me tell you that they exist, but at a price. There is no freely available shapefile for this, AFAIK.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe, thanks and I guessing its outrageously priced right?

Comment: It's still not clear what you are looking for. Are you looking for a shapefile? if so, please put that in the question.

Comment: We had purchased it from mapmyindia. You can contact them here to find the price: http://www.mapmyindia.com/about/contact-us

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe, its quite expensive. I was looking for this information for a small project. Hopefully, they will put it into public domain sooner.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for open data for which there is an [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

Maymyindia charges approx Rs. 14Lakhs for entire India pincode data. They charge around Rs. 80k per city.

Comment: Do you have any affiliation to Mapmyindia?